# jQuery.noConflict causing issue with jQuery animate

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I have just installed an element that slides in from the right. After calling jQuery 1.7.1 I have this in my footer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element').animate({right:'0px'}, 3000).css('overflow', 'visible'); });
```

See an example here http://jsfiddle.net/7e92Y/11/

The theme I have it installed in is unfortunately quite bloated with tons of other jQuery. But I've narrowed it to exactly one line in all the .js files as to why the above function won't work.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

If I eliminate that line, the element slides in as expected, but it also breaks other jQuery elements. I have been running around in circles trying to get it to work.

Is it something obvious I am missing that I need to do?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can you modify your fiddle representing the same condition?

Comment: Without looking at the rest of the code, my only suggestion is to change `$` to `$j` in your footer.

Comment: f* me.. I tried that Bruno, but I didn't put it after BOTH `$`, just the 2nd one. That did it.. man, what a headache that was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer so the question has an answer: change `$` to `$j` in your footer.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$j` to the jquery tag yet you are calling `$`. I would recommend replacing `$` with `$j` in the footer.